# Browser won't connect to svn server

Tags: svn, firefox, visualsvn-server

This has been driving me nuts. For some reason, I can't access my svn repository using a browser in this laptop that I'm using right now (firefox & ie) The connection just times out.

I'm at home right now and the server is in another room. It connects OK there and it also connects OK in my virtual machine in this same laptop. I'm pretty stumped right now and can't figure out why this is happening.

I've also checked the proxies and I'm 100% sure I'm not using any at all. The virtual machine running on this laptop is XP 32bit and this one is a Win7 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

Try another browser from the same machine to rule out Firefox configuration problem.
Try [`Fiddler`](http://www.fiddler2.com/dl/Fiddler2BetaSetup.exe) to see what's the request Firefox is sending.
Check the DNS resolution of your SVN server host name.

Comment: IE 8 doesn't connect either (if you consider that a browser) :).

Comment: So, now you know it's something with your machine setup, not a Firefox issue. (And yes, I do consider IE8 to be a browser :-))

Comment: Don't add [belongs-on-XXX] tags. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your firewall settings on the server?